# Spring build a RESTful web service tutorial, whitelabel error page

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-tool-suite, spring-rest

**Question:** 
Why am I getting the whitelabel error page?

**Exact Error:**

Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

```
Thu Sep 17 12:11:02 CDT 2015
    There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
    No message available
```

**Background:** 
I am following the spring.io getting started guide to build a RESTful web service using spring.

https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/#scratch

I am using Spring tool suite and I followed the tutorial to key.

**My code:**

Greeting.java

```
package hello;

public class Greeting {

    private final long id;
    private final String content;

    public Greeting(long id, String content){
        this.id = id;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
}
```

GreetingController.java

```
package hello;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    private final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();


    @RequestMapping("/greeter")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World") String name) {
        return new Greeting( counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template, name));
    }

}
```

Application.java

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);     
    }

}
```

Comment: What endpoint are you hitting with your browser/http client? You have the RequestMapping set to `/greeter`.

Comment: That is what I was doing wrong thank you! Although, now I am getting a illegalStateException, tomcat server failed. I am trying to see if I can change the port for my localhost to see if that'll fix the issue..

Comment: java.net.BindException: Address already in use

Comment: Fixed it and got it to work. Thank you so much!